# Show answered date in wiki answers

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

Sometimes browsing through a question reveals answers that going up and up through time: you may see the most upvoted answer have, say, a score of 600 and the second one 200. However, upon further focus, you notice the second one is quite new in comparison and is attracting most of the new votes. That is, it is likely to be the new good way to do something, and eventually will surpass the most upvoted answer.

Taking this into consideration, whenever I am not sure about what is the *good way* to do something I tend to check the box where the answerer name is displayed to see when it was posted.

However, I find it annoying that wiki answers do not display this information.

See [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/1983854):

> [image]

Here we have an own-accepted, wiki answer and another one that has more votes. To check the date of the wiki answer we have to go to the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8636711/revisions) and see the information (in this case we get  `answered Dec 26 '11 at 14:40`, which reveals that both answers occurred the same day).

Taking this into consideration, wouldn't it be good to display the "answered" information for wiki answers as well?

Comment: [FYI] if you hover over *community wiki* it will tell you when it was made a CW.  It may not be the same date and time but I wanted to let you know.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, I wasn't aware of that! However, as you say, it may or may not be the same date.

Comment: Maybe it can change it to be the creation date and you have to check the rev history to get the change date.  This way the user box doesn't get another row added to it making it bigger than a standard user box.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's a good point. Knowing the data when a post was converted to a wiki-answer is way less relevant than when it was posted.

Comment: Why is the community wiki information even in the user box for who answered it? I feel it should be in the updated user box (to the left) like [this image](http://i.imgur.com/alNleTT.png).

Comment: Is the creation date even *relevant* to the quality of the post? Especially since it is a wiki post, it may have been edited later, even drastically. I think using the revisions page is the most reliable way to determine this.

Comment: Fully agree @Pluto - maybe you should post the suggestion on here?